# rewrite wordpress login url when it contains an affiliate ID

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

we are doing some affiliate tracking on a wordpress membership site with mod_rewrite. basically the URLS are domain.com/AFF_ID and AFF_ID is the members tracking id, this all works perfectly.

the problem comes in when members go to the affiliate tracked url domain.com/AFF_ID and login using domain.com/AFF_ID/wp-admin this generates a 500 error. rather than tell them not to use the affiliate id in the login URL i need to create a rule to remove everything before /wp-admin and the domain

basically

domain.com/could-be-anything/wp-admin

becomes

domain.com/wp-admin

i have tried various rules with no effect or i create an redirect loop. i would post what i have tried but they dont come close to working.

thanks for any suggestions,

Sean

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/wp-admin$   /wp-admin [L,NC]
```

It redirect any given path followed by `/wp-admin` to `yourdomain.com/wp-admin`
ex.
   `www.yourdomain.com/anything/wp-admin`
 redirect to:

```
www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin
```

Comment: Does WordPress  not allow you to handle routing at application level, instead of web server level? I don't usually like these approaches since they are not scalable at all.

Comment: this is the only way that i know for routing with wordpress. usually i work in plain php or with mcv frameworks like Laravel that obviously  can easly handle routing.

Comment: [Here's actually more information on WordPress routing.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141087)

Comment: Reading comments dont seems an affordable solution  kind of  "hacking wordpress to do something it was not meant to do". By the way in the op user says that already he's handling routing on servel level.

Answer (score 0):

i have not tried the above answer, looks like it may work with 1 exception, the registration url used wp-admin and we do want to track that page. 
here is what i have that is working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/wp-admin
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !.*action=
RewriteRule ^.*/wp-admin /wp-admin [R=301,L]
```